# Best way to load images on Android Client from Server

Tags: java, android, image, web-services

Should we load images on Android Client directly using the URL 
OR
Do we fetch Images via a Server Side APP/or a webservice(Passing a image name appended to URL) .
Which way is better.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/

Answer (score 2):

Downloading the large images for each image and then down sampling is going to be very inefficient. First the download size is larger than needed. Second you need to load it into memory to perform the down sample and third down sampling is somewhat slow.

You can use web api which return you a list of thumbnail urls and full image urls that you can lazy download as the view comes on screen and use the cache to keep them around a while. Make sure you down sample the sizes of the thumbnails as well. I would then when the user clicks on an image go download the full image and on the background when it arrives down sample it before displaying it.

You need to implement the [LazyLoading](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) is the best way to download the image from url asynchronously.

Check out the [tutorial](http://androidexample.com/Download_Images_From_Web_And_Lazy_Load_In_ListView_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=112&aaid=134)

You need read the [documentation before proceeding to working with images.](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can load images from server wit direct URL using ImageLoader

first get universal-image-loader-1.8.6-with-sources.jar from net and set in lib , built path .

```
//------ImageLoader from lib.    ------for load images-----------------------
protected ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
DisplayImageOptions options;
//----------------------------------------------------------------
```

// Initilization of imageLoader---------------

imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(con));

//---------------------

//Initilizing option .........for image.....................

```
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_image)
    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.image_for_empty_url)
    .cacheInMemory()
    .cacheOnDisc()
    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
    .build();

    //------------------------------------------------------
```

//pass URL like--->  http://www.xyz.com/xyz/upload/image//2013/08/30/1377865578220.jpg //---pass holder, and display images if exist
// Constant.Image_URL+List.get(position).get("photo") <--- your full URL with images name
//holder.img is image view where you wont to set image

```
imageLoader.displayImage(Constant.Image_URL+List.get(position).get("photo"), holder.img, options);
```

// using these code you get images from url

Answer (score 0):

if you are not using high resolution bitmaps then it perfectly suits you.

http://howrobotswork.wordpress.com/2013/06/02/downloading-a-bitmap-asynchronously-with-volley-example/